# Salvar arquivos de um DataGridVIew

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-excel, datagridview

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar todo o conteúdo que foi passado para um DataGridView e salvar ele em um arquivo Excel. Até o momento eu tenho isso:

```
private void btnDiretorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory;
            folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = openFileDialog.InitialDirectory;
            folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<string> selectedPath = listaArquivos(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);

                foreach (string s in selectedPath)
                {
                    grvShowFile.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(s), s);
                }
            }
        }
```

Esse código é de um botão que seleciona todos os arquivos de um diretório e suas subpastas.
Note que o DataGridView está sendo preenchido normalmente.

```
 private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.cboParametro.Text == "" || this.cboParametro.Text == "Ola"){
                MessageBox.Show("Parametro inválido, por favor tente novamente.");
            }

            string[] arrayParam = { "FROM", "SELECT", "WHERE", "UPDATE", "" };
            //Dictionary<string, string> getParam = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //getParam.Add("FROM", "WHERE");
            //getParam.Add("SELECT", "Private");
            StreamReader DirectorySR = new StreamReader(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
            while (!DirectorySR.EndOfStream)
            {
                string read = DirectorySR.ReadToEnd();
                DirectorySR.Close();

            }
        }
```

É aqui onde estou me perdendo, esse botão precisa receber um parametro que vai ser passado pelo usuário ( OK! ) e logo em seguida carregar os arquivos que foram passados no DataGridView ( É aí que não estou conseguindo dar continuidade ) e ler arquivo por arquivo 
passando aquele array que foi criado com as palavras específicas.

Sou iniciante em C# e não consigo dar continuidade a essa parte.

Comment: seu pergunta está um pouco confusa, não dá para entender exatamente o que você precisa, você fala de salvar o conteúdo do `DataGridView` em um arquivo Excel e depois no código, dá a entender que você quer fazer uma pesquisa nos arquivos que estão no `DataGridView` utilizando o `arrayParam`, dê uma olhada em [ask] e ajuste sua pergunta

Comment: Rodolfo, também não entendi se você quer exportar o conteúdo do grid para o excel ou quer abrir um arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com os objetos de [interoperabilidade do Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/dd264733.aspx)

Segue um exemplo de uma função que faz a exportação dos dados de um `DataGridView`

```
private void ExportToExcel()
{
    // Creating a Excel object.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

    try
    {

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

        int cellRowIndex = 1;
        int cellColumnIndex = 1;

        //Loop through each row and read value from each column.
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvCityDetails.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dgvCityDetails.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                if (cellRowIndex == 1)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dgvCityDetails.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dgvCityDetails.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                cellColumnIndex++;
            }
            cellColumnIndex = 1;
            cellRowIndex++;
        }

        //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful");
        }               
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        excel.Quit();
        workbook = null;
        excel = null;
    }

}
```

O exemplo completo você pode encontrar no seguinte link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Export-DataGridView-62f1f8ff